# I've written a C# program. Can I put it on my WP7 phone?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'd like to convert my program to a WP7 app.  It's written in C# and basically just stores my blood sugar readings and it can also display a graph based on that data.

I'm assuming I'll have to re-write the program in Silverlight, but I was wondering if anyone else had tried something like this (making a C# program into a WP7 app) and what advice they could offer?  For instance, a web site that talks about converting a .Net program to WP7 format?

Thanks for any advice!

EDIT: The existing interface is WinForm.  I can change that to WPF, if need be.  I just wasn't sure about the process and thought maybe someone here had gone through it before and could offer advice.

Comment: "converting a .Net program to WP7 format" Not sure what the question is. WP7 supports .NET natively. I think the question in its current form is overly broad.

Comment: what's the existing interface it uses?  Is it displaying the graph in Windows Forms?  WPF? a Website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert it to run on Windows Phone, but it will require a significant effort, as the current program is developed using Windows Forms.  Windows Phone uses a version of Silverlight - which will likely mean that your logic will work as-is, but the user interface will need to be rewritten.

That being said, typically, a desktop-developed application will always need a fair bit of working to function correctly, and meaningfully, in a phone's form and shape.  The overall interface size and design typically has to be modified.

Comment: Thanks, Reed.  I appreciate the advice.  Since my logic is separated from the display, I can rewrite that easily enough.  I was hoping that someone here may know of a resource that could indicate caveats and pitfalls of getting a .Net program to run on a Windows Phone.  As simple as my program is, though, I can just rewrite the whole thing using the Windows Phone version of Silverlight.  I'll see if I can find a book on Amazon for beginning Windows Phone development.  Thanks, again!